# Irrespective of keys need to push values into array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here keys may come dynamic. so i need to get values only irrespective of keys.

```js
var test = []
var arrayObj = [
  {
    "abc": {
        "value": "1"
    },
    "def": {
        "value": "TERN"
    },
    "aec": {
        "value": "SASU"
    },
    "rtg": {
        "value": "FI"
    },
    "ttyg": {
        "value": "9"
    },
    "yty": {
        "value": "uyMFG"
    }
},

 {
    "abc": {
        "value": "1"
    },
    "def": {
        "value": "EXT"
    },
    "aec": {
        "value": "SAM"
    },
    "rtg": {
        "value": "FINISH"
    },
    "ttyg": {
        "value": "5"
    },
    "yty": {
        "value": "MFG"
    }
}]
function printValues(obj) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[key] === "object") {
            printValues(obj[key]);   
        } else {
           test.push(obj[key])
        }

    }
        

}
printValues(arrayObj);

    console.log(test);
```

Am getting this

```
["1","TERN","SASU","FI","9","uyMFG","1","EXT","SAM","FINISH","5","MFG"]
```

but, i need to get as below output

```
[["1","TERN","SASU","FI","9","uyMFG"],["1","EXT","SAM","FINISH","5","MFG"]]
```

Am i doing in the right way or i can get better way than my approach ?
Please suggest me how to achieve this. I don't know where i am going wrong.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do here: even though a function is recursive, it never tries to track the level of recursion, pushing the values into the same result regardless of how deep (in param) it's right now. Do you even need recursion? Perhaps all the processed objects always have the same structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't particularly need the funciton to be recursive, you can achieve this with some `Object` and `Array` methods.

```js
var arrayObj=[{abc:{value:"1"},def:{value:"TERN"},aec:{value:"SASU"},rtg:{value:"FI"},ttyg:{value:"9"},yty:{value:"uyMFG"}},{abc:{value:"1"},def:{value:"EXT"},aec:{value:"SAM"},rtg:{value:"FINISH"},ttyg:{value:"5"},yty:{value:"MFG"}}];

const output = arrayObj.map(obj => {
  return Object.values(obj).map(({value}) => value)
})

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

In simplest form you can map the array and return a map of the Object.values().

This assumes the depth is known (as per example) and the `value` property is consistent

```js
const res = arrayObj.map(e => Object.values(e).map(o => o.value))

console.log(res)
```

```html
<script>
   var arrayObj=[{abc:{value:"1"},def:{value:"TERN"},aec:{value:"SASU"},rtg:{value:"FI"},ttyg:{value:"9"},yty:{value:"uyMFG"}},{abc:{value:"1"},def:{value:"EXT"},aec:{value:"SAM"},rtg:{value:"FINISH"},ttyg:{value:"5"},yty:{value:"MFG"}}];
</script>
```

Comment: why u copy my answer ;)

Comment: Thank you :) but @Nick given answer first.. so accepted his answer

Comment: @Nick It was only posted 2 minutes later, so it is likely he did not see your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `for..in` on arrays.

> Use `for..of` on iterables like an array, string, etc

> Use `for..in` on objects.

```js
var arrayObj = [
  {
    abc: { value: "1" },
    def: { value: "TERN" },
    aec: { value: "SASU" },
    rtg: { value: "FI" },
    ttyg: { value: "9" },
    yty: { value: "uyMFG" },
  },
  {
    abc: { value: "1" },
    def: { value: "EXT" },
    aec: { value: "SAM" },
    rtg: { value: "FINISH" },
    ttyg: { value: "5" },
    yty: { value: "MFG" },
  },
];
var test = [];
function printValues(arr) {
  for (var obj of arr) {
    const temp = [];
    for (let key in obj) {
      temp.push(obj[key].value);
    }
    test.push(temp);
  }
}
printValues(arrayObj);
console.log(test);
```

Comment: Thank you :) but @Nick given answer first.. so accepted his answer